# Dynamic Field with JSP and HTML

Tags: html, jsp

```
<form id="send" action="doaddnewuser.jsp" method="post">
                <div id="controls" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;height:500px;width:750px;float:left;">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <%
                                String buffer = "<tr><td><label for=''" + "productid" + "''>Product ID *</label></td> <td><select name='" + "productid" + "'>";
                                try {
                                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE", "*****", "*****");

                                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from product");
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        buffer = buffer + "<option value='" + rs.getString(1) + "'>" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>";
                                    }
                                    buffer = buffer + "</select> </td></tr>";
                                    response.getWriter().println(buffer);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e);
                                }
                            %>

                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="price">Price *</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" size="60"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="debitaccount">Debit Account *</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="debitaccount" value="" size="25" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="creditaccount">Credit Account *</label>
                                <td><input type="text" name="creditaccount" value="" size="25" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="quantity">Quantity *</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="25" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="transactiondate">Transaction Date *</label></td>
                                <td><input type="date" name="transactiondate" value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="totalprice">Total Price *</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="totalprice" value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="vat" style="text-align:justify" >15% VAT</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="vat" value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>   </td>
                                <td>   </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td> 
                                    <input id ="submit" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>                        

                </div>
            </form>
```

The above is my HTML and JSP code to construct sales input form - but as the page runs the product id field which is constructed by the JSP goes to the left top corner instead of 
being shown with the other controls

can you please help me why it wanders off.

P.S. the idea is to populate the product_id field from database

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `response.getWriter().print(..)` inside the jsp, do the code below instead.

```
     <%
                                    String buffer = "<tr><td><label for=''" + "productid" + "''>Product ID *</label></td> <td><select name='" + "productid" + "'>";
                                    try {
                                        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE", "*****", "*****");

                                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from product");
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                            buffer = buffer + "<option value='" + rs.getString(1) + "'>" + rs.getString(1) + "</option>";
                                        }
                                        buffer = buffer + "</select> </td></tr>";
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        System.out.println(e);
                                    }
                                %>
<%=buffer%>
```

The `<%=buffer%>` will print the content of the **buffer** variable in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest you to do this instead:

```
<form id="send" action="doaddnewuser.jsp" method="post">
            <div id="controls" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;height:500px;width:750px;float:left;">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                          <tr>
                          <td>
                                <label for=''" + "productid" + "''>Product ID *</label></td> <td><select name='" + "productid" + "'>

                        <%

                            try {
                                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE", "*****", "*****");

                                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from product");
                                while (rs.next()) {
                        %>
                                 <option value = "<%=rs.getString(1)%>"> <%=rs.getString(1)%> </option>
                        <%

                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }
                        %>

                                </select> </td></tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="price">Price *</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" size="60"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="debitaccount">Debit Account *</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="debitaccount" value="" size="25" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="creditaccount">Credit Account *</label>
                            <td><input type="text" name="creditaccount" value="" size="25" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="quantity">Quantity *</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="25" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="transactiondate">Transaction Date *</label></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="transactiondate" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="totalprice">Total Price *</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="totalprice" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="vat" style="text-align:justify" >15% VAT</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="vat" value="" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                            <td>   </td>
                            <td>   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td> 
                                <input id ="submit" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>                        

            </div>
        </form>
```